# What meaning of (*SomeStruct)(nil)?

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand this piece code of an ORM library, but I cannot understand what is meaning of `(*User)(nil)`? First parenthesis is a pointer to User struct, then what is 2nd parenthesis stand for?

```golang
type User struct {
    Id     int64
    Name   string
    Emails []string
}

for _, model := range []interface{}{(*User)(nil), (*Story)(nil)} {
    err := db.CreateTable(model, &orm.CreateTableOptions{
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: The construct `t(x)` is a type conversion of `x` to type `t`. In your  case `x` is the literal nil` and the type `t` is `*SomeStruct` which is "pointer to SomeStruct". The ( ) around `*SomeStruct` are to prevent parsing this as `*(SomeStruct(nil))`.

Answer (score 5):

In Go, `nil`s [can by typed](https://go101.org/article/nil.html), so that a `nil` of the type `*User` is different from a `nil` of the type `*Story`. So `(*User)(nil)` is actually a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) that makes a typed `nil` pointer. Further more, the typed pointer is then implicitly converted to `interface{}` according to the [`CreateTable`](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg/orm#CreateTable) signature. Interfaces always [store their type along with the data](https://github.com/teh-cmc/go-internals/blob/master/chapter2_interfaces/README.md#anatomy-of-an-interface), and that information can be accessed in runtime using [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), like [it happens in ORM](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/master/orm/model.go#L46).

Because in Go types are not "first-class citizens", i.e. you can't just pass a type around as a value, they use a typed `nil` pointer idiom that essentially allows providing the desired model type as an argument to `CreateTable` without creating an instance of it or messing with `reflect` in the client code.

Comment: is it the same as `var x *User` ?(i think readers might be interested into that)

Comment: How is it implemented ? AFAIK, C++ can provide type information via RTTI which stored inside `VPTR`, but `nullptr` doesn't contains `VPTR`, so no information can be provided by `nullptr`. So how can golang provide reflection information via `nil` ? is there any black magic, like hidden argument ?

Comment: @mh-cbon yes, just without an explicit variable.

Comment: @Zang MingJie i cant answer because idk all details and c++, but go has 2 "kinds" of pointer https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer @ bereal i was not asking for myself ; )

Comment: @ZangMingJie as far as I understand the mechanics here, untyped `nil` is first converted to the typed value (which type is known already at compile time), and then implicitly converted to `interface{}` which is required by `CreateTable`. And interfaces always keep the actual type along with the value. I hope someone will correct me if that's not accurate.

Comment: Updated the answer to include that `interface{}` part.

Comment: Yes, interfaces store the concrete type. That's the reason for the [nil error confusion](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error) but here the same mechanism is taken advantage of.